# Shared Sessions Cookies with Different Usernames in Different Tabs

Tags: authentication, cookies, tabs

How does one use sessions cookies to manage logins?

The naive approach using, say, ASP.NET Forms Authentication sets a cookie when a user logs in. Cookie is then checked on every call to the server.

But cookies are shared between browser tabs. This seems problematic.

I log in as Dave in TAB A and proceed to do all work as Dave.

More or less simultaneously, I log in as Alfonso on TAB B. The cookie from this login overwrites the Dave cookie.

So all work in TAB A is done as Dave, the "Logged in as" UI element says Dave, but when I submit, the server performs all work as if it were done as Alfonso.

This does not seem good. What is best practice here? Is the only solution to use cookieless sessions by putting the encrypted username in the URL of each call?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to ensure your logic properly handles authentication. This is a common problem, as you need to account for issues like this, as well as "what happens if I submit the form even though the user has since been logged out?"

1. You shouldn't be able to login as Alfonso when you are already logged in as Dave. You have to logout as Dave first. If a login screen was already present on a tab even though Dave is logged in, the postback from logging in should realize that the user is already logged in (so Alfonso can't login).
2. Every time you save data, you should ensure the person performing the work is 1) still logged in and 2) the correct person.

If you want some old tab to automatically realize the user has since logged out, or is now someone else, that would require a bit more work (AJAX)... without it, bullet 2. from above will handle your problem.

Comment: I can certainly prevent Alfonso's login if Dave's session cookie comes with the request. But isn't there a time window problem here: Dave logs in on TAB A. Before the response comes back with the cookie, Alfonso logs in on TAB B. Alfonso's login will be accepted because it also has no session cookie accompanying it.

Comment: This sounds like a not very plausible scenario. How slow is your login that someone could open up a new tab and login before you get a response? When would this happen in real life? In this scenario, one person is still only ever logged in so the issue in your 2nd to last paragraph in the post would never occur.

Comment: It's not likely, I agree. "Unlikely" is not the usual standard I use when designing software to be managed securely.

Comment: @dkeisen I didn't say "unlikely". I said "not very plausible" as in, "not reasonable". If by some miracle your situation happens... then *still* only one person will be logged in and bullet 2) of my answer *still* keeps your application secure.

Comment: The difference I think is "secure" vs "user perception." Similarly if Dave is logged in, has unsaved work, leaves his computer, Alfonso sneaks over, opens a new tab, and logs him out, and then goes back the tab, and Dave comes back and hits save.... there will be a problem and the data shouldn't save. Whether Alfonso logged in as himself or not. Now if you want the UI to automatically reflect that Dave has been logged out, or is now Alfonso, like I said in my answer that will take more work.